# Should there be a comma before "such that" in this context?

Tags: commas, mathematics

In mathematical papers, one often encounters "such that". I was wondering in what contexts you would need to place a comma before that.

An example sentence is the following:

> Take an element out of this set[,] such that this element satisfies this condition.

The context is, there are a lot of elements in the set, but not all of them satisfy the condition. Should a comma be placed here or not?

I believe there should be a comma, since this is similar to the situation where you have a defining clause or a restrictive clause. However, when I look it up I cannot find any examples that specify the use of a comma before "such that".

Comment: Using set symbols, there would be no comma. x∈R | x  > 0. (I may have spacings wrong.) But the English really is best as 'Select a member of the set, this member being such that ....' Your transliteration of the symbolic shorthand is unusual, and one could argue either way (after first arguing on overall acceptability).

Comment: I usually see "such that" phrases in mathematical statements as appositives, much like "My brother Vincent" where the comma is used only when the information added by the appositive is not necessary. In other words, if I only have one brother, I would write "My brother, Vincent," since my brother's name is not needed for clarity. If, however, I have other brothers, there would be no comma because I need to specify which brother. "Such that" in your example begins an appositive-like phrase that is necessary to understand the "set"; therefore, no comma.

Comment: In short, the standard style (but it's still not an absolute rule), is to use a comma with nonrestrictive information, and omit it with restrictive information.